# VMs, Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: virtual-machine, connection

I set up 3 VMs Oracle VirtualBox with ubuntu 14.04, and I want to use one of them as Management Node an the other 2 as  Compute Node.

Did anyone have idea about that?

Thanks in advance.

Soma

Comment: Does those VM need to be connected with outer host network?

Comment: No it does not.